# Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $V \subseteq W$. Suppose that $\dim V = \dim W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am working on the following proof:

> Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ with $V \subseteq W$ ( that is that every vector $\vec{v} \in V$ is also in $W$). Suppose that $\dim V = \dim W$. Prove that $V = W$.

I am not convinced that this is even true. Could anyone supply some assistance?

Comment: Try assuming that it's not true.  That is that there is some $\vec w \in W$ s.t. $\vec w \not\in V$.

Comment: What is your definition of dimension? The maximal size of a linearly independent set?

Comment: @user237799 Did I answer your question?  Is there something you'd like me to elaborate on?

Answer (score 2):

Sketch of proof:

$V$ is $k$-dimensional means that $V$ contains at least one set of $k$ linearly independent vectors $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k$ and cannot contain a set of $k+1$ linearly independent vectors.

$W$ is $k$-dimensional means that $W$ contains at least one set of $k$ linearly independent vectors $w_1, w_2, \dots, w_k$ and cannot contain a set of $k+1$ linearly independent vectors.

$V \subseteq W$ means that $\forall v \in V, v\in W$.  This implies that $v_1, v_2, \dots v_k \in W$.

Now suppose that $W$ has at least one vector $w_i$ that's not in $V=\operatorname{span}(v_1, \dots, v_k)$.  Then $W$ has at least one set of $k+1$ linearly independent vectors -- that set being $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k, w_i\}$.  But $W$ is $k$-dimensional.  Contradiction.

So $\forall w\in W, w\in V$.  Thus $V=W$.$\ \ \ \ \square$